# Youtube Data API ChannelBanners.Insert call failing with 500 error code

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Alright here's the situation. I'm building a simple system to automate some processes on youtube channels i own. I have a CMS. I've built my structure and everything is working well, i have enabled both APIs ( Youtube Data API v3 and ContentID API ) and i successfully make requests. I can retrieve uploads on all channels, change thumbnails and brandingSettings, but i tried the ChannelBanners.insert call and it fails with 500 error code message null.

I have authorized my app with :

```
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($network->clientEmail, array(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'), $key);
        $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
```

and this is the function i call to upload banners. You can see that i wrapped everything in my project in classes.

```
public function uploadBanner($banner, $channelId)
    {
        try {
            $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            $this->client->setDefer(true);
            $chan = new Google_Service_YouTube_ChannelBannerResource();
            $insertRequest = $this->youtube->channelBanners->insert($chan, array(
            "onBehalfOfContentOwner" => $this->networkID));

            $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
                $this->client,
                $insertRequest,
                'image/jpeg',
                null,
                true,
                $chunkSizeBytes
            );
            $media->setFileSize(filesize($banner));

            $status = false;
            $handle = fopen($banner, "rb");

            while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
              $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
              $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);

            }

            fclose($handle);

            $this->client->setDefer(false);
            $thumbnailUrl = $status['url'];
            echo $thumbnailUrl;
            $listResponse = $youtube->channels->listChannels('brandingSettings', array(
                'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => $this->networkID,
                'onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel' => $channelId,
                'managedByMe' => true,
            ));

            $responseChannel = $listResponse[0];
            $responseChannel['brandingSettings']['image']['bannerExternalUrl']=$thumbnailUrl;
            $updateResponse = $youtube->channels->update('brandingSettings', $responseChannel);
        }
        catch(Google_Service_Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

The method is failing with the above error code, and i searched for this issue but not much information about it. Some say 500 error code is not your apps fault and there is nothing you can do as the server refuses your requests. Sometimes i get Backend Error. Even the code sample in the documentation does not work. And the sample in the documentation is not meant for **Youtube Partners**. Can anyone help me how to get this working. Im trying to upload banners on channels i manage on my CMS (onbehalfOfContentOwner) through Youtube API and PHP. Thanks !